# JavaFX: How to make a Node partially mouse transparent?

Tags: event-handling, mouseevent, javafx-2, transparency

## Simplified Problem:

Make one Node "A" that is on top of another Node "B" to be half transparent to MouseEvents, so the Events will reach the underlying Node "B". Both Nodes are of equal size but Node "A" has a half transparent background image so one half of Node "B" is visible.

## Real Problem:

I have a menu of tabs. Each tab can be dragged to expand the corresponding menu layer. Therefore each tab layer is a Pane with a partially transparent background (basically a polygon) of which the transparent part should be also transparent to MouseEvents.

The illustration (which I can't post yet, see link: [Illustration of tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmkfG.jpg), the dark green line is the border of the green Pane) shows the basic principle: just imagine only the tabs are visible and the layer itself can be pulled to the right to view it's content.

So the question is, how do I make a region of a Node transparent to MouseEvents without making the whole Node transparent?

Thank you for your help!

#### Update:

To clarify the simple problem here is the corresponding code:

```
//Create parent group
Group root = new Group();

//Create linear gradient, so one side is transparent
Stop[] stops = new Stop[] { new Stop(0, Color.rgb(0, 255, 0, 0.0)), new Stop(1, Color.rgb(0, 255, 0, 1.0))};
LinearGradient lg1 = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, stops);

//Create the rectangles
Rectangle A = new Rectangle(100, 50, lg1);
Rectangle B = new Rectangle(100,50, Color.RED);

//Add eventHandlers
A.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Clicked A");
    }
});
B.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Clicked B");
    }
});
root.getChildren().addAll(B, A);

//Add to Scene..
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't think much, but can suggest thing : create a rectangle, set its color to transparent (seems, Color.TRANSPARENT). Make it not mouse transparent, and bind its height to the part of height of target node "A". Put it over target node "A", and write code of event passing to the underlying node "A". Make node "A" transparent. Is it working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the `pickOnBounds` property, it *may* help in your situation, but it is not clear to me without seeing your code attempt which fails for the simplified problem.

[node.setPickOnBounds(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setPickOnBounds%28boolean%29)

> If pickOnBounds is true, then picking is computed by intersecting with the bounds of this node, else picking is computed by intersecting with the geometric shape of this node.

The code below demonstrates how this may be used by creating a square overlaid by an `ImageView` for an `Image` which contains tranparent pixels.  If `pickOnBounds` is set to true for the ImageView, then, even if you click on the transparent pixels in the image, the ImageView will receive the mouseClick event.  If `pickOnBounds` is set to false for the ImageView, then, even if you click on the transparent pixels in the image, the ImageView will not process the click and the click event will be received by the node behind the image.

[image: mousepick]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PickOnBoundsDemo extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { Application.launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    final Rectangle back  = new Rectangle(128, 128);
    back.setFill(Color.FORESTGREEN);
    final ImageView front = new ImageView("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/aha-soft/free-large-boss/128/Wizard-icon.png");
    // icon: Linkware (Backlink to http://www.aha-soft.com required)

    final StackPane pickArea = new StackPane();
    pickArea.getChildren().addAll(
      back, 
      front
    );

    final ToggleButton pickTypeSelection = new ToggleButton("Pick On Bounds");
    final Label pickResult = new Label();

    Bindings.bindBidirectional(front.pickOnBoundsProperty(), pickTypeSelection.selectedProperty());

    front.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        pickResult.setText("Front clicked");
      }
    });

    back.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        pickResult.setText("Back clicked");
      }
    });

    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 10;");
    layout.getChildren().setAll(
      pickArea,
      new Label("Click inside the above area to test mouse picking."),
      pickTypeSelection,
      pickResult
    );
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try this and add the background Image as an ImageView instead of setting the CSS background-image property.

Comment: Your solution works! Thank you very much. I had to set pickOnBounds(false) for all nodes containing the ImageView object, so the Event would not be caught by an parent node.